Specific Tmux sessions are disappearing
My work requires me to run processes for long amounts of time and therefore I usually use Tmux sessions to run things overnight. However, I'm noticing that sometimes when I log into the server the particular Tmux session that I was using has disappeared. It doesn't even seem to be the case that the server is shutting down because the other Tmux sessions are fine.
I thought that the problem might have been when there's inactivity in the server itself the server logs out automatically, but this is happening even when I make sure to log out manually.

How exactly do you run the processes in tmux? Do you run shells in panes and type (or paste) commands there? Or do you use tmux new-session something or so? Please see "Terminating the tmux session" in this answer of mine and this other answer of mine. Can it be your tmux sessions terminate naturally like described in the linked answers?
